# Floor plan for J.T. Kirk's apartment in "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan" and "Star Trek III: The Search for Spock"

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan, the-search-for-spock

My brother is building a loft apartment in his new shop building. Being a big Trekkie, he wants to recreate Kirk's apartment in San Francisco . A cursory review of Trek floor plans shows his TOS Enterprise quarters, but nothing about his Bay Area dwelling. Screen shots are plentiful, but I'd really like to find a floor plan or some sort of rendering to use in designing the loft apartment.

Has anyone seen a floor plan of of Kirk's San Francisco apartment in a periodical or some other source from either of the two films?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I knew once I posted this I would find it...

The blueprints were auctioned on Prop Store. I have attached them here for reference:
[image: Kirk's Apartment 1][image: Kirk's Apartment 2][image: Kirk's Apartment 3][image: Kirk's Apartment 4]